Safety of unpressurized 9000 foot elevation 6 months after mild heart attack?
For clarity and context this is not a health or medical question, nor am I asking for permission or medical advice.  Rather I would like context and information and to draw upon the experience of this community so I can have an intelligent conversation with my doctor.
I have been invited on a 2 hour flight at 9500 feet in an unpressurized cabin.  I had a mild heart attack 6 months ago and 2 stents implanted.
Are there others on this sub that have experience that would be helpful for my discussion with my doctor?

This is not an aviation question, but a health care question. Please seek advice from a qualified doctor.

Regarding your comment on the edits you made, this site is not designed for open discussion or getting opinions. If there isn't a specific factual answer you're asking for, the question isn't good for the site format.

This is not Reddit, sites are not called “subs”.

This post is locked to prevent the OP from vandalizing it.  Defacing posts that have been made, even ones own posts, is not permitted on Stack Exchange.  The question was asked, and even though it is off topic, it received an answer that has been up-voted.  This may be useful information for those who come later, and it's unacceptable to remove the question which was asked, even when one isn't pleased with the answer or the community's decision regarding the off-topic character of the question.

Ask your doctor, not strangers on the internet.

Wise advice.  For the OPs information though, airliners are typically pressurised to the equivalent of 8000ft

Thanks for providing information.  That is helpful.

@electronpositron the demand on your heart is dependent on oxygen availability and usage.  So, it may be safe as long as you do not exert yourself at that altitude.  Again, an expert opinion from a doctor can put you much more at ease.  It will depend a lot on what you can do at sea level (climb 3 flights of stairs, etc).
